# Microsoft Azure DevOps Repo: search for text/code in specific branch

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm embarrassed to ask what *should* be a simple thing to figure out....

However, when I'm viewing a specific branch in an Azure DevOps repository online (e.g., when reviewing a PR), I can't figure out how to perform a search of that branch's code.

I see a global search textbox at the top, as follows:
[image]

And I see a textbox for searching the branch for file/folder *names*, as follows:

[image]

But what I *don't* see is a textbox for searching the *contents* of the files in that branch....e.g. for finding occurrences of `someFunction()` or `somePropertyName` or whatever inside the code files for that particular branch.

Did Microsoft really omit this functionality?  Or am I missing something?  How do we perform such a search?

Comment: Hi friend, does the answer below resolved your question? If yes, appreciate for marking it as answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, input content in the global search textbox at the top and search:

[image]

Now, you can select your repo and branch the dropdown list:
[image]

By default, code search only applies to your default branch. You may add up to 5 more here:
[image]
Please notice that when a new branch is configured for search via “include/exclude searchable branches”, the branch list of search is not immediately populated with the newly configured branch. This happens because it takes some time to on-board a new branch and make is searchable. It takes up to 12 hours to fully initialize the branch.

You can also refer to this document about [search your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/code-search?view=azure-devops).

Comment: This answer assumes that the Code Search extension is installed in your Azure DevOps instance. May require admin rights to install/configure.

Answer (score 5):

what they aren't telling you (and I just went through this today) is that you have to have a "successful" search in order to get the Branch: filter to appear & be selectable.  "Failed" searches give you all the filter dropdowns but you cannot change them.

Answer (score 2):

In fairness you'd just be better off actually Doing a Pull and using git to search the code then ..

Comment: Sadly this still seems to be case, 1.5 years later...in fact all I want is to be able to search the changed lines in a PR, but I can't work out how to do that either.

Comment: It kind of sucks because in my case I want to search for a certain thing across all our repositories. There are a hundred repos in our organization and I need to change all instances of a thing everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Best answer I've found is to use the global search, and broaden or refine your search as desired: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/get-started-search?view=azure-devops, however by default DevOps only makes the master branch searchable by this method. You may need to add other branches to the Searchable list - but this requires EditPolicies right in DevOps.